# Adding Array in SQLite While Loop

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using this -> http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429 to create my own custom listview.

For my project, I am using while loop to get data and getting data back.

The original code is :

```
DownloadClass data[] = new DownloadClass[] { 
    new DownloadClass("test", "test"), 
    new DownloadClass("test", "Sunny")
};
```

However for my case..

```
DownloadClass data[] = new DownloadClass[] {};
SQLFunctions entry = new SQLFunctions(this);
entry.open();
highestID = entry.getHighestId();
for (int l = 1; l < highestID; l++) {
    Long longVal  = Long.valueOf(l);
    new DownloadClass(entry.getName(longVal).toString(), entry.getURL(longVal).toString());
}
```

The listview appears to be empty because I know the data is not inserted. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT : 
my DownloadClass :

```
public class DownloadClass {
        public String name;
        public String url;
        public DownloadClass(){
            super();
        }

        public DownloadClass(String name, String url) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.url = url;
        }
    }
```

My new Activity

```
DownloadClass data[] = new DownloadClass[]; // need to work on this
    SQLFunctions entry = new SQLFunctions(this);
    entry.open();
    highestID = entry.getHighestId();
    Log.e("HIGHEST ID", highestID.toString());
    if (highestID > 1) {
    for (int l = 0; l < highestID; l++) {
        Long longVal = Long.valueOf(l);
        //String name = entry.getName(longVal);
        //String id = entry.getURL(longVal);
        //Log.e("NAME", name + " - " + id);
data[l] = new DownloadClass(entry.getName(longVal).toString(),entry.getURL(longVal).toString());
        }
    }
entry.close();
```

Comment: You have to just put this line DownloadClass data[] = new DownloadClass[highestID]; after get highestID and it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know what happen..

```
DownloadClass data[]; 
SQLFunctions entry = new SQLFunctions(this);
entry.open();
highestID = entry.getHighestId();
data[] = new DownloadClass[highestID];
for (int l = 0; l < highestID; l++) {
Long longVal  = Long.valueOf(l);
data[i] = new DownloadClass(entry.getName(longVal).toString(), entry.getURL(longVal).toString());
}
```

Also start your loop with 0 index.. instead of 1..

**Update:**

First of all you are dynamically creating array of object. SO you have to know the size of array.

Second your loop is start with index 1, it should be 0.

Comment: Don't just feed him the solution, tell him what's wrong, and how to improve.

Comment: @Recursed - As he want to know, how to fill array of object and he stuck over it. And I don't think these two lines mash up him. It happens on beginning stage.

Comment: Yes, but he needs to **learn** so that he will know **why** there is a problem and how to fix it in the future. If we just spoonfeed every answer to people, especially on simple problems like these, we perpetuate bad programming. People need to learn not to copy and paste every chunk of code they can grab, but instead **learn** from experienced programmers, and be able to develop their own code.

Comment: @MrYanDao - Yeah, a experienced programmer knows how the code works.

Comment: @Recursed : I certainly agree with you. I've been programming with other language before and just came to Java - Android. That's why I faced lots of problems :(

@user370305 Thank you so much for your replies! I do get what you mean, and I changed my code accordingly. However, it seems that `DownloadClass data[]` needs to be `DownloadClass data[] = new DownloadClass[]; `
I've updated my first post. Hopefully you will see where did I go wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @MrYanDao - I defined DownloadClass[] data; data = new DownloadClass[highestID]; to allocate memory (size) of array..

Comment: @MrYanDao - You're array will always be empty if you initialize it like that. You're saying you want a new array of size zero. If you don't know the size your array is going to be, I suggest using an ArrayList.

Comment: To Recursed and user370305 : I've managed to solve the problem. Thanks to both of you. Thank you so much for both of your help!

Recursed : I am currently learning Java so I'll be damn noobish at it. You're right. I have to learn and understand the code instead of just plain copy-and-paste. I will try my best learn and understand more! Thank you!(:

user370305 Thank you so much for your help! Sorry I sound noobish. New to this :( I'll read and understand what you post for me. Thank you so much!(:

Answer (score 1):

You're not ever adding your new `DownloadClass` object to your array. You also need to allocate size if you're going to use an array instead of an `ArrayList` (which to be honest is probably what you want).

As you iterate through the loop you need to assign the new object to a position in the array.

`data[i] = new DownloadClass(...);`

Comment: I know. And that's why I am asking, how do I add it into the array.

Comment: Your loop starts at 1, which I'm not sure I understand, but what I've shown above is how you add to an array. This is a very simple programming concept, and I suggest you read up on arrays before you try to take this too much further.